# What is the correct syntax for a conditional section in ractive?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I'm attempting a very simple [conditional expression](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/expressions) in a ractive template. **See [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FarWn/13/)** - here's my data:

```
{name: 'steve'}
```

Here's my template:

```
value of name is: {{ name }}      
{{#if (name === 'steve')}}this should work{{/if}}
```

Which renders:

```
value of name is: steve
(nothing else)
```

Why is the conditional not working? How can I make a section that only applies if 'name' meets a particular string value?

Comment: I note `{{ name === 'steve' ? "this should work" : "" }}` works. But I'd like a section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiddle is using a very old version of Ractive - 0.3.7. If you use the latest stable version instead (0.6.1) it works as expected. I can't include a link to the fiddle because of SO's draconian new rules, but you can find RactiveJS Latest at the bottom of the Frameworks and Extensions dropdown on the fiddle

Comment: I think the poster used version 0.3.7 because it’s currently the latest version [on cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ractive.js). As well using as the Frameworks and Extensions drop-down, you can get a [link to the actual latest version](http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js) from [Ractive’s homepage](http://www.ractivejs.org/).

Comment: Thanks @RoryO'Kane - have opened an [issue](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1543) to look into using cdnjs's auto-update so that this doesn't happen again